# How can I normalize breadcrumb trails while maintaining the order of the breadcrumbs?

Tags: database, data-modeling, breadcrumbs

I have some web-scraped data that I would like to normalize and store in a database but I am finding it very challenging to model a way to store breadcrumb trails, those paths that appear at the top of shopping websites (ie. Home > Video Games > Consoles > PS4), in a way that avoids redundancy and makes querying easy.

For instance, say my scraped data looks like this:

```
+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|    Product    |     Store     | Price  |    Crumb_1    |   Crumb_2   |   Crumb_3   |   Crumb_4   |   Crumb_5   |
+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| Playstation 4 | Electromart   |  500.0 | Electronics   | Gaming      | Consoles    | Playstation |             |
| Xbox One      | Electromart   |  500.0 | Electronics   | Gaming      | Consoles    | Xbox        |             |
| Playstation 4 | Gamestart     |  550.0 | Consoles      | Modern Gen  | Playstation |             |             |
| Xbox One      | Gamestart     |  525.0 | Consoles      | Modern Gen  | Xbox        |             |             |
| Playstation 3 | Gamestart     |  50.00 | Consoles      | Retro       | Playstation |             |             |
| PS 4          | Future Store  |  565.0 | Entertainment | Electronics | Video Games | Consoles    | Playstation |
+---------------+---------------+--------+---------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

I would like to be able to query for all products with "Playstation" as one of its crumbs without having to resort to something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM PRODUCTS
WHERE CRUMB_1 = 'Playstation'
OR CRUMB_2 = 'Playstation'
OR CRUMB_3 = 'Playstation'
OR CRUMB_4 = 'Playstation'
OR CRUMB_5 = 'Playstation'
```

At the same time, I would like to be able to reassemble the crumbs in the order that they appeared so that the crumb-trail can be easily read.

I thought maybe an associative table(TRAILS) to connect PRODUCTS to CRUMBS would work:
[image]
But it seems my foreign keys need to be primary keys elsewhere and I can't make trail_id a primary key since it needs to be non-unique.

I feel as though what I am trying to do *is possible* but I can't find a solution that works. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't think the model would work.. What if you have the same product in different trails? Are you sure the product belongs to a trail or does it belong to a crumb?

Comment: Products occasionally appear twice with different trails (which are composed of different crumbs). For instance, sometimes the crawler will pick up a Playstation in, say, Future Store's sales section so it'll have a crumb trail like Sales > Electronics > Consoles. I am not sure if this means a product belongs to a trail or crumbs.

Comment: I would say it belongs to a crumb. Moreover, you need an extra table for linking the crumb and the product, since a product might be in more than one crumb.. (let's say, `consoles` and `offers`). However, I'm not able to decide it, only you know your current use case and how the application is going to be used. I don't think this question suits stackoverflow (probably it would go better in Software Engineering, but seems too unspecific to be answered)